# Create subdomain for each company that signs up

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

So i have built an application which allows companies to sign up. Once the company have created an account they can then add their own users.

So i have a database which contains all companies and users just separated by a company ID essentially.

Now the way i have it at the minute is that they just log in at the main website, but i came across another web application that creates a subdomain for each company that signs up.

For example company1.mywebsite.com and the next company would be company2.mywebsite.com.

How can i achieve this so that when a company signs up it automatically creates a new subdomain which their company name first?

Comment: take a look at this page:http://vikku.info/programming/php/create-subdomain-dynamically-in-php-code-to-create-subdomains-in-server-using-php.htm

Answer (score 1):

You would require a [Wildcard DNS record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), which would point to your application.

From there, the application would fetch the domain name from `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, and you could use that to decide which company you are working with.